# how to handle Python error while webscraping?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape the weather details for cities from google. However in the below code output I get empty information. Also can please some one tell how can I make city(London) dynamic so that I can get weather update for any city.

My vs code --->

```py
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 



headers = {'User-Agent' :'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

#getting information from the wesite
r = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search?q=weather++london') 

#prasing the information
soup =BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')


info =  soup.find_all('div', classs_ = 'wob_t q8U8x')

print(info)
```

My output is empty instead of temperature in numerical value.
output-->

[]

Answer (score 0):

You could use the pip package [geonamescache](https://pypi.org/project/geonamescache/)

With this simple loop you can then loop over each city:

```py
import geonamescache
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

gc = geonamescache.GeonamesCache()
cities = gc.get_cities()

for city in cities:
    # Generating the url  
    url = "https://google.com/search?q=weather+in+{}".format(cities[city]['name'])
    
    # Sending HTTP request 
    request_result = requests.get( url, cookies = {'CONSENT' : 'YES+'} )
    
    # Pulling HTTP data from internet 
    soup = BeautifulSoup( request_result.text , "html.parser" )
    
    # Finding temperature in Celsius.
    # The temperature is stored inside the class "BNeawe". 
    temp = soup.find( "div" , class_='BNeawe' ) 

    print("The temperature of {} is: {}".format(cities[city]['name'], temp.text))
```

If you want any other data you can adapt this by searching for other classes or id's.